# Problem generating random matrix of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku generator on a 4 by 4 grid in JavaScript. 
So I declare a matrix of objects such as {number: 0, cbd: 1}, which represent the number that is going to be on the cell, and a state variable that controls if that cell can later be dug (cbd):

```
var matrix = new Array(4).fill({number: 0, cbd: 1}).map(() => new Array(4).fill({number: 0, cbd: 1}));
```

I then used this function to fill the grid, respecting all the 3 sudoku restraints: no repetitions on row, columns and square:

```
fillmatrix4(matrix,tam){
var numberList = [...Array(4+1).keys()].slice(1); //[1,2,3,4]
for(var k = 0; k < 4**2; k++){
    var row = Math.floor(k/4);
    var col = k%4;
    if (matrix[row][col].number == 0){
        numberList.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5); //shuffles the array
        for(var q = 0; q < numberList.length; q++){
            var ids = matrix[row].map(a => a.number); //creates an array with the number property from all cells in that row
            if (!(ids.includes(numberList[q]))){ //check if number is in row
                if ((matrix[0][col].number != numberList[q]) && (matrix[1][col].number != numberList[q]) && (matrix[2][col].number != numberList[q]) && (matrix[3][col].number != numberList[q])){ //check if number is in column 
                    var square = [];
                    if (row<2){It is used to find out what subgrid we are in
                        if (col<2){
                            square = [matrix[0][0].number, matrix[0][1].number, matrix[1][0].number, matrix[1][1].number];
                        } else {  
                            square = [matrix[0][2].number, matrix[0][3].number, matrix[1][2].number, matrix[1][3].number];
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (col<2){
                            square = [matrix[2][0].number, matrix[2][1].number, matrix[3][0].number, matrix[3][1].number];
                        } else {  
                            square = [matrix[2][2].number, matrix[2][3].number, matrix[3][2].number, matrix[3][3].number];
                        }
                    }
                    if (!(square.includes(numberList[q]))){ //check if number is that subgrid
                        matrix[row][col].number = numberList[q]; //if number not in row, column and square, adds it to matrix
                        if (this.checkGrid(matrix,tam)){ //returns true all matrix is filled
                            return matrix;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that this function works. I tested it on a matrix of integers, but I need that each individually cell has that variable cbd.

But now, with the matrix of objects above declared, it's not "shuffling". The result is always a grid filled like this:

```
a | a | a | a
b | b | b | b
c | c | c | c
d | d | d | d
where a,b,c,d are numbers from 1 to 4.
```

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Shuffling with `.sort()` like that won't really work. Also when you pass an object to `.fill()`, you fill the array with references to the same single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
Array(4).fill({number: 0, cbd: 1})
```

this fills every entry with a reference to the same object in memory. Graphically, it looks like:

```
                   .-----------.
                   | number: 0 |
                   | cbd: 1    |
                   `-----------`
                    ^  ^  ^  ^
                    |  |  |  |
variable `matrix`: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Changes made on any of these array indices will mutate the same underlying object.

Here's a minimal, complete, reproducible example:

```js
const arr = Array(4).fill({foo: "bar"});
arr[0].foo = "baz";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
console.log(arr);
```

You can see all 4 entries reflect the change made to the first object. Note that the stack snippet `console.log` of the array shows "ref" to an object id for 3 of the 4 buckets.

To fix the problem, use `.map` to generate distinct objects:

```js
const arr = Array(4).fill().map(() => ({foo: "bar"}));
arr[0].foo = "baz";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
console.log(arr);
```

Or, in your code:

```js
const matrix = Array(4).fill().map(() => ({number: 0, cbd: 1}))
  .map(() => Array(4).fill().map(() => ({number: 0, cbd: 1})));

console.log(matrix);
```

(the `new` is unnecessary).

As an aside, try to avoid deeply nested blocks. Consider writing helper functions to handle some of this logic and make the code easier to follow.

Also, if you're looking for good shuffling in JS, I recommend looking into the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @ggorlen nice definition. have got one noobar question. how you made graphical def?:)))

Comment: You mean ASCII boxes? I just typed it into the text box, but there are tools like http://asciiflow.com you can use.